# Django. Show error message on current page

Tags: python, django

Help me please! I'm trying to show error message:

In forms:

```
    def clean_form(self):
       url = self.cleaned_data['text']
       if url == 'qwe':
           raise ValidationError("Error")
       return self.cleaned_data
```

In view:

```
def main_site(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Form(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.clean_form()
        link = form.cleaned_data['text']
    ...
```

But when I send 'qwe' in form:

[image]

And press 'send'. Take:

[image]

But I want to see Error on same page. What's I should be do?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only checking the `text` field, therefore you should override the `clean_text` method.

```
def clean_text(self):
   url = self.cleaned_data['text']
   if url == 'qwe':
       raise ValidationError("Error")
   return url
```

Remove the `clean_form()` line from your code. Django will automatically call the `clean_text` method for you when you check `if form.is_valid()`.

See the docs on [cleaning a specific field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) for more info.

If you were checking multiple fields at the same time, then you would override `clean`. See the docs on [cleaning fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) for more information about that.